# External resources in JSFiddle not working

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle

I want to ask a question about jquery menu aim, then I have to put my code in `jsfiddle` with some external resources. I did [this](http://jsfiddle.net/X8w5M/2/) but it didn't work. Could any one tell what's wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: That's it. Please provide us the links of any external resources you tried. Also please the fiddle you tried.

Comment: I already put it  `I did >>>this<< but it didn't work.` in that. Anyway here it is  http://jsfiddle.net/X8w5M/2/.

Comment: @Domo Github is not a CDN. You have to use CDN links to embed external resources to jsfiddle. Let me find some for you.

Comment: @Domo Here is a working fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/X8w5M/16/

Comment: To the folks who put this on hold... The answers may be opinion based but @Domo asked a question that has 1 or more actual solutions. His original Fiddle is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're linking to the github pages that display those files *not the actual files* that live on github. No, github isn't a CDN but it can absolutely be used to serve files.

As an example, try changing:
https://github.com/kamens/jQuery-menu-aim/blob/master/jquery.menu-aim.js
to
https://raw2.github.com/kamens/jQuery-menu-aim/master/jquery.menu-aim.js

and
https://github.com/kamens/jQuery-menu-aim/blob/master/example/css/bootstrap-responsive.css
to
https://raw2.github.com/kamens/jQuery-menu-aim/master/example/css/bootstrap-responsive.css

There are some issues with linking to files directly on github. Namely, everything is served as text/plain. As an alternative, you can use the http://rawgithub.com/ service. So the jQuery Menu link would become:
`http://rawgithub.com/kamens/jQuery-menu-aim/master/jquery.menu-aim.js`

Updated fiddle pointing at the correct github URLs: http://jsfiddle.net/X8w5M/12/

**EDIT**:
Note that the bootstrap CSS doesn't work in that fiddle because fiddle expects CSS to be served as text/css. Changing the bootstrap CSS link to http://rawgithub.com/kamens/jQuery-menu-aim/master/example/css/bootstrap.css brings it back to life.

**EDIT 2**
Here's a working fiddle with using rawgithub to serve the CSS and github to serve the JS. http://jsfiddle.net/X8w5M/18/

Comment: Thanks Will. Here is a working fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/X8w5M/16/

Comment: But the style in `bootstrap.css` seems not working properly.

Comment: @domo did you see my edit?

Comment: I'm not clear, why some external resources use `rawgithub` and some are not :/

Comment: @Domo "There are some issues with linking to files directly on github. Namely, everything is served as text/plain." and "Note that the bootstrap CSS doesn't work in that fiddle because fiddle expects CSS to be served as text/css."

Answer (score 0):

Github is not a CDN. You have to use CDN links to embed external resources to jsfiddle. You can use the below links as external resources.

http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.menu-aim/0.1/jquery.menu-aim.min.js

http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css

http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js

Try these.

Comment: -1 because this just isn't true at all. For sure, CDN is a better way to go but what if you want to point JS Fiddle at a github hosted file that isn't available via CDN?

Comment: @Will What he added are available from a lot of CDN's. Github is a version control but not a CDN.

Comment: @Will If it isn't available that's okay. But this is a different case, they are available right. Anyway both of our answers work. I will +1 your answer. Adios.

Comment: ha, I just tried to remove my downvote of yours but it says I can't unless you edit it. Specifically because it looks like CSS only works when served as text/css *which github doesn't do*.

Comment: @Will I will edit mine you edit yours. The fiddle works if we remove the top:100% property from Bootstraps css.